# Load images in JavaFX from resources with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am trying to load an image of a certain playing card for a game I am building in JavaFX.

I have created a resource folder under `src/main/resources/png` that holds `PNG` images that are named to match the card type. My goal is to access these images for rendering to the view based on the name of the card from the file `src/main/java/rummy/GUI.java`.

My file structure looks like this.
[file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siDfq.png)

I have tried several things based on some other results but none are working.

Here is what I have now that results in `Invalid URL or resource not found`

```
private void drawHand(Pane canvas) {
    ArrayList<Tile> tiles = game.getCurrentPlayer().getHand().toList();

    for (Tile tile: tiles) {
        ImageView tileImageView = drawTile(tile);
        canvas.getChildren().addAll(tileImageView);
    }
}

private ImageView drawTile(Tile tile) {
    ImageView tileImageView = new ImageView();
    Image image = new Image("../../resources/png/" + tile.toString() + ".png");
    tileImageView.setImage(image);
    return tileImageView;
}
```

I have also tried variations of...

```
BufferedImage tileImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/png/" + tile.toString() + ".png"));
Image image = new Image("resources/png/" + tile.toString() + ".png");
```

I am not sure if I correctly set up my `resources` folder as a resources folder or if I am missing something else but I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: How is `toString` implemented in `Tile`?

Comment: try this `new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(png/" + tile.toString() + ".png"))`